# Menu de pedidos en C#

Tags: c#

Llevo unos días intentando hacer un trabajo en el que me piden hacer un menu de pedidos en C#, pero me sale el siguiente error:

> File "", line 6, in **main** Failed example:
> printf '%d\n1\n%d\n1\n%d\n1\n' -1 -1 -1 | mono /tmp/program.exe Expected:
> How many burgers do you want? Not a valid value. How many burgers do you want? How many fries do you want? Not a valid value. How many
> fries do you want? How many drinks do you want? Not a valid value. How
> many drinks do you want? The total amount of your order is 5.5 euros.
> Press any key. Got:
> How many burgers do you want?
> Not a valid value. How many burgers do you want?
> Press any key.

Adjunto código aquí:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace actForClase5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string h, p, b;
            float preu = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("How many burgers do you want? ");
            h = Console.ReadLine();
            int h1 = int.Parse(h);

            if (h1 <= 0) {
                Console.WriteLine("Not a valid value. How many burgers do you want? ");
                h = Console.ReadLine();
            } else {
                preu += h1 * 3;
                Console.WriteLine("How many fries do you want? ");
                p = Console.ReadLine();
                int p1 = int.Parse(p);
                if (p1 <= 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Not a valid value. How many burgers do you want? ");
                    p = Console.ReadLine();
                } else
                {
                    preu += p1 * 1;
                    Console.WriteLine(" How many drinks do you want? ");
                    b = Console.ReadLine();
                    int b1 = int.Parse(b);
                    if (b1 <= 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Not a valid value. How many drinks do you want? ");
                        b = Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        preu += b1 * 3;
                        Console.WriteLine("The total amount of your order is " + preu);
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que hay una verificación del programa en base a su salida. Este es el resultado esperado:

> How many burgers do you want?
>
> Not a valid value. How many burgers do you want?
>
> How many fries do you want?
>
> Not a valid value. How many fries do you want? How many drinks do you want?
>
> Not a valid value. How many drinks do you want?
>
> The total amount of your order is 5.5 euros.
>
> Press any key.

Este es el resultado que produce tu código:

> How many burgers do you want?
>
> Not a valid value. How many burgers do you want?
>
> Press any key.

La salida es diferente porque hay algunas cosas que arreglar y mejorar en tu código.

- [`int.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse) lanza una excepción si no se puede convertir la cadena en un entero sin embargo no estás controlando ninguna posible excepción. Mejor usa [`int.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse) que devuelve true si la conversión es válida.
- Los `if` están mal planteados. Si el valor no es válido lo pides nuevamente, pero el programa termina ahí ya que el código que debería seguir está en otra rama del condicional. La solución es sacar ese código del else:

  ```
  // Hamburguesas
  if (noValido){
      // ...
  }
  // Papas
  if (noValido){
      // ...
  }
  // Bebidas
  if (noValido){
      // ...
  }
  ```
- Los if se evalúan una sola vez. Por lo tanto, si ingresas un valor inválido más de una vez, no se vuelve uno valor valido. Para eso puedes usar un `while`.
- Dale nombres descriptivos a las variables.
- Hay código repetitivo. Puedes crear una función para solucionarlo.

Los últimos dos puntos son los más importantes. Aunque no afecten el resultado directamente, son 2 factores que influyen en tu habilidad para resolver el problema. Si escribes código limpio será más difícil cometer errores.

Corrigiendo y mejorando el código, quedaría así:

```
static int GetValidNumber(string message){
    Console.WriteLine(message);
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    int number;

    while (!int.TryParse(input, out number) || number <= 0) {
        Console.WriteLine("Not a valid value. " + message);
        input = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    return number;
}

const float burgerPrice = 3;
const float fryPrice = 1;
const float drinkPrice = 3;

static void Main(string[] args){
    float price = 0;
    int burgers = GetValidNumber("How many burgers do you want?");
    price += burgers * burgerPrice;
    int fries = GetValidNumber("How many fries do you want?");
    price += fries * fryPrice;
    int drinks = GetValidNumber("How many drinks do you want?");
    price += drinks * drinkPrice;
                        
    Console.WriteLine("The total amount of your order is " + price);
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key.");
}
```

Puedes probar el código [aquí](https://tio.run/##jVNNT8MwDL3nV5idtgHTEOI0Jg6TgAOgCRAcEAfTeiWiTSYnYapgv32kX6MfaCxSqyZ@9nsvdgNzHGimzcYZqSJ4SI2lZCKEwoTMEgMCDOyl5lmMhs7ElwC/Ar8xMGcdMSb5SXGeLWPRygCksnBF9gljGd655I24byxnFL6uwYgGvynZEjOtjI5p9MzS0o1U1K@AkwawrCLV0lmYQpV2TxjmWS14pkPl/N5UPbB6lzFB/8ADRo@czpEN9fOqR6BdlTSA7@/yE86nMB5AU3a@utJ7d9oCwmfmPns7GkEPDuFvS4XO/fysGzsm61htDf6CRODrWFjEGi28OY6I5yx9N6dwOmkEF957GTlpRkJ/0R@1rHaLP7U3d4tSlZ19eQXkyLQaW9RalmXG3e4U6owPtuald61XkKBKt5BQQ6odrFDZi17rYgqGw@kWPKz77tIuWNJO0gKwF2UBHW7vssuW3@VOuhKxF1@JHdZa1J2o6sf6Z1If3wmsthgDJtp5qXqRKWDQHPqhlyYf3Jy6JeePYnP2Aw6ZnQ9KR3X9xdyuxXqzGYsTUT0/).

Por cierto, nota que en la salida esperada el resultado es 5.5. Pero le diste valores enteros a los precios de los productos. Al sumar números enteros obtienes otro entero. Así que asegúrate de establecer correctamente los precios.

Comment: Buenas! Ahora me sale el siguiente error: Expected:
    How many burgers do you want? Not a valid value. How many burgers do you want? How many fries do you want? Not a valid value. How many fries do you want? How many drinks do you want? Not a valid value. How many drinks do you want? The total amount of your order is 5.5 euros.
    Press any key.
Got:
    (2)Cannot open assembly '/tmp/program.exe': No such file or directory.

Comment: @Capulta solo dice que no encontró en programa. ¿Esta compilando bien? ¿Lo estás probando de la misma forma que cuando escribiste la pregunta?

Comment: ya lo he solucionado, gracias!